# How can I start hono without k8s?

Tags: eclipse-hono

I tried to install hono for test purpose, i tried k8s ( minikube and non -minikube). It didn't work for me by now. I am looking for other alternatives.  For example, can I start honor using docker compose ? I checked Ditto that it can be started using docker compose.

@Vigkam , I saw one your message, you had installed hono in one machine. Did you use k8s ?

Thanks